# Covariant derivative and orthogonal projection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $V$ be a smooth vector field along a curve $c$. The covariant derivative of $V$ along $c$ at the point $c(t)$ us given by

$\frac{D_cV}{dt}(c(t))=\lim_{s\to t}\frac{P_{c(t),c(s)}V_{c(s)}-V_{c(t)}}{s-t},$ where we define $P_{c(t),c(s)}$  to be the parallel transport of the tangent vector $V_{c(s)}$ to a tangent vector at the point $v(t)$.

Geometrically, the covariant derivative $\frac{D_cV}{dt}(c(t))$ represents the projection of $dV/dt$ onto the tangent plane of the surface, but I can't prove it clearly, how to give a intuitive way to see this?

Here we consider $c$ as a curve from a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: "projection . . .  onto the surface" . . . the surface?  Which surface?  Inquiring minds want to know!  Cheers!

Comment: You should specify your setting. You're doing a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$? A surface in $\Bbb R^3$? A submanifold of a Riemannian manifold with the induced Riemannian connection? ... You have to understand the *connection* geometrically. How is parallel transport defined?

Comment: @TedShifrin let's say it's a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You didn't answer my other question. I define parallel transport in terms of the covariant derivative. Of course, one can do it in the other way, but you have to tell me how parallel transport is defined for you.

Comment: @TedShifrin the tangent vector maintains constant length and constant angle with the geodesic. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's not the definition of parallel translation. And how are geodesics defined without covariant derivatives? You need to fill in your original question with a lot more background on what your book/course is using.

Comment: Do you agree the geometric meaning of covariant derivative?